# how to shift based on a regular expression using perl?

Tags: perl

how to shift the top element from array based on a regular expression using perl? Also these are datarecords, meaning I have the input record separator ($/) set to

$/='#';

for example, the following text file contains this data record.

```
    #dddddddddd
    ccccccccccc
    eeeeeeeeeee
    fffffffffff
```

I would like to remove the # sign and keep the text, for example:

```
    dddddddddd
    ccccccccccc
    eeeeeeeeeee
    fffffffffff
```

Comment: Show us more about what you are doing or want done with an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to manipulate a text file, a one-liner seems like the best solution. This will edit the file and keep a backup in "inputfile.txt.bak".

```
perl -pi.bak -we 's/^#//' inputfile.txt
```

Or you can do a shell redirection:

```
perl -wpe 's/^#//' inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

These will try to alter all the lines in the file. If you just want the first line altered you need something different:

```
perl -wpe 's/^#// if ($. == 0);' inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't confuse [`shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) with regex substitution.

`shift` will remove the first element from the *array*, not string.

A regex substitution can deal with removal of the leading `'#'` sigil.

The first element of the array would be `$array[0]`.

If a regex substitution is applied to this first element, the `'#'` is removed:

---

```
my @array = ( '#dddddddddd', 'ccccccccccc', 'eeeeeeeeeee', 'fffffffffff' );

$array[0] =~ s/^#//;

print $array[0];  # 'dddddddddd'
```

Comment: I forgot to mention the input record separater ($/) is set to $/ = '#';  because this would allow me to read in a datarecord.

Comment: @jbs Perhaps you should add such important information to the question.

Comment: Thanks TLP, I updated the question to include I set the input record separator to $/='#';

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be related to arrays. It appears you are just dealing with strings.

This removes a leading hash mark for the string `$line`:

```
$line =~ s/^\#//;
```

Comment: I couldn't remember if it was. When in doubt, I escape.

Comment: You might want to use brackets `[]` for "escaping" as a habit since in a number of regex variants you backslash to turn ON a special character sense. And in this case, you have a small reason to be cautious, the `#` is special in (`s///x`) expanded regex mode.